# Calculating Most and Least significant byte(MSB, LSB) with Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm kinda new to `Swift` and trying to learning the language and working on some communication protocol at the same time.

The protocol requires to implement two functions calculating Most and Least significant byte (`MSB`, `LSB`) for given `int` value and the input cannot be greater than `0xFFFF`.

For example, if input is `286(0x11E)` then it should return `0x01` for `MSB` and return `0x1E` for `LSB`.

I know there are many references for other languages but could not get what I want and rewrite into `Swift`.

Please help
Thank you

Comment: What result do you expect for 32-bit integer 0x00123400? (MSB,LSB) = (0x00, 0x00) or (0x12, 0x34) or some other?

Comment: Oh forgot to mention that input cannot be greater than 0xFFFF. @OOPer

Comment: You'd better edit your post and include such important info in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple bit manipulation.

Seeing 0x11E in binary representation:

```
(higher bits are always 0) 0000 0001 0001 1110
                       MSB ^^^^ ^^^^
                       LSB           ^^^^ ^^^^
```

So, you just need bit-shifting and bit-masking with bitwise AND operation.

```
let data = 286
let lsb = data & 0xFF
let msb = (data >> 8) & 0xFF

print(String(format: "lsb=0x%02x, msb=0x%02x", lsb, msb)) //->lsb=0x1e, msb=0x01
```

Comment: thank you so much. it's so much simpler than i thought